# Customise symfony2 embeded form template

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 version 2.3. I created two entites Outlet and Voucher. The voucher entity represent the ebmded form. I already embeded voucher to outlet form and it works fine. Now, I am trying to customise my voucher embeded form template. I want to apply the same style as outlet fields. How can i do that?
My formType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('file')
            ->add('alt')
            ->add('area')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('phone')
            ->add('latitude')
            ->add('longitude')
            ->add('vouchers', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new VoucherType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
            ))
            ->add('enabled')

    ;
}
```

Twig file:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate', 'class': 'form-horizontal', 'id': 'frm-create'} }) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.name, 'Outlet Name', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet name.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.category, 'Outlet Category', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.category) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.category, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Choose your Outlet Category.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.description, 'Outlet Description', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.description) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.description, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet description.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.file, 'Image', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label col-lg-2 col-sm-2'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        {{ form_widget(form.file, {'attr': {'class' : 'default'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Upload your Outlet image.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.alt, 'Image description', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.alt) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.alt, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter the image description.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>       
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.area, 'Outlet Area', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.area) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.area, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Choose your outlet area.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.location, 'Outlet Location', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.location) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.location, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet location.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.phone, 'Outlet Phone', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.phone) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.phone, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control', 'data-mask':'(999) 999-9999'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet phone.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                   
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.latitude, 'Latitude', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.latitude) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.latitude, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet latitude.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.longitude, 'Outlet Longitude', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label'} }) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form.longitude) }}
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        {{ form_widget(form.longitude, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} }) }}
                        <p class="help-block">Enter your outlet longitude.</p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            {{ form_errors(form.enabled) }}
                            <label>
                                {{ form_widget(form.enabled) }} {{ form_label(form.enabled, 'Status') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // On récupère la balise <div> en question qui contient l'attribut « data-prototype » qui nous intéresse.
        var $container = $('div#mybook_adminbundle_outlet_vouchers');

        // add a link in order to add a new voucher
        var $lienAjout = $('<a href="#" id="add_voucher" class="btn">Add a new voucher</a>');
        $container.append($lienAjout);

        // On ajoute un nouveau champ à chaque clic sur le lien d'ajout.
        $lienAjout.click(function (e) {
            ajouterCategorie($container);
            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        // On définit un compteur unique pour nommer les champs qu'on va ajouter dynamiquement
        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        // On ajoute un premier champ directement s'il n'en existe pas déjà un (cas d'un nouvel article par exemple).
        if (index == 0) {
            ajouterCategorie($container);
        } else {
            // Pour chaque catégorie déjà existante, on ajoute un lien de suppression
            $container.children('div').each(function () {
                ajouterLienSuppression($(this));
            });
        }

        // La fonction qui ajoute un formulaire Categorie
        function ajouterCategorie($container) {
            // Dans le contenu de l'attribut « data-prototype », on remplace :
            // - le texte "__name__label__" qu'il contient par le label du champ
            // - le texte "__name__" qu'il contient par le numéro du champ
            var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'Voucher n°' + (index + 1))
                    .replace(/__name__/g, index));

            // On ajoute au prototype un lien pour pouvoir supprimer la catégorie
            ajouterLienSuppression($prototype);

            // On ajoute le prototype modifié à la fin de la balise <div>
            $container.append($prototype);

            // Enfin, on incrémente le compteur pour que le prochain ajout se fasse avec un autre numéro
            index++;
        }

        // a function that add the delete voucher link
        function ajouterLienSuppression($prototype) {
            // Création du lien
            $lienSuppression = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>');

            // add the link
            $prototype.append($lienSuppression);

            // Ajout du listener sur le clic du lien
            $lienSuppression.click(function (e) {
                $prototype.remove();
                e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a VoucherType class and add modify the fields in there. In this case my garantiaType is your voucherType class.

```
<?php

namespace daci\contratosBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class garantiaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fecha_emision','date', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                )
                ->add('fecha_vencimiento','date', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                )
                ->add('fecha_entrega_estimada','date', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                )
                ->add('fecha_recibido_daci','date', array(
                        'label' => 'Fecha de recibido DACI',
                        'required' => true,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                )
                ->add('fecha_entrega','date', array(
                        'label' => 'Fecha de devolución al proveedor',
                        'required' => true,
                        'widget' => 'single_text',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                )
                ->add('empresa_emite_garantia', 'text', array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'label' => 'Empresa que emite la garantía',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                    )
                ->add('tiempo_de_garantia', 'text', array(
                        'label' => 'Plazo de vigencia',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        )
                    )
                ->add('estado', 'choice', array(
                        'empty_value' => 'Elija una opción... ',
                        'choices'   => array('0' => 'No Vigente', '1' => 'Vigente'),
                        'required'  => true,
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                     ))
                ->add('isRecibido', 'checkbox', array(
                        'required'  => false,
                        'label'     => 'Recibido',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 25px;',
                                        ),
                    )
                )
                ->add('porcentaje','integer', array(
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                        'attr'  =>  array('help'=>'text help'),
                        ))
                ->add('monto','integer', array(
                        'label' => 'Monto de la garantía',
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 35px;',
                                        ),
                      ))
                ->add('comentarios', 'textarea', array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'label_attr' => array(
                                            'style' => 'vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0px;',
                                        ),
                        'attr' => array(
                                    'style' => 'width: 485px;',
                                )
                        )
                )
                ->add('archivo', new DocumentType(), array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'label' => ' ',
                        )
                );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'daci\contratosBundle\Entity\garantia',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'garantia';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!

This is my javascript code. In my case, I have three embebed classes (like your voucherType but three of them) so I had to modify it for each one of them. here is my code and there is where I suggested to use the code sorrounding with divs and stuff you need. In my case I use < h r > tag to separete them.

javascript code:

```
// Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
var collectionHolderGar = $('ul.garantias');
var collectionHolderSeg = $('ul.seguimientos');
var collectionHolderVis = $('ul.visitas');


// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addGarantiaLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_garantia_link">Agregar Garantia</a>');
var $addSeguimientoLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_seguimiento_link">Agregar Seguimiento</a>');
var $addVisitaLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_visita_link">Agregar Visita</a>');


var $newLinkLiGar = $('<li></li>').append($addGarantiaLink);
var $newLinkLiSeg = $('<li></li>').append($addSeguimientoLink);
var $newLinkLiVis = $('<li></li>').append($addVisitaLink);


$(document).ready(function(){

    // add a delete link to all of the existing tag form li elements
    collectionHolderGar.find('li').each(function() {
        addGarantiaFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });

    collectionHolderSeg.find('li').each(function() {
        addSeguimientoFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });

    collectionHolderVis.find('li').each(function() {
        addVisitaFormDeleteLink($(this));
    });

    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    collectionHolderGar.append($newLinkLiGar);
    collectionHolderSeg.append($newLinkLiSeg);
    collectionHolderVis.append($newLinkLiVis);

    // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
    // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
    collectionHolderGar.data('index', collectionHolderGar.find(':input').length);
    collectionHolderSeg.data('index', collectionHolderSeg.find(':input').length);
    collectionHolderVis.data('index', collectionHolderVis.find(':input').length);

    $addGarantiaLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addGarantiaForm(collectionHolderGar, $newLinkLiGar);
    });

    $addSeguimientoLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addSeguimientoForm(collectionHolderSeg, $newLinkLiSeg);
    });

    $addVisitaLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addVisitaForm(collectionHolderVis, $newLinkLiVis);
    });

});


function addGarantiaForm(collectionHolderGar, $newLinkLiGar) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = collectionHolderGar.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolderGar.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    collectionHolderGar.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLiGar.before($newFormLi);

    // add a delete link to the new form
    addGarantiaFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
}
function addSeguimientoForm(collectionHolderSeg, $newLinkLiSeg) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = collectionHolderSeg.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolderSeg.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    collectionHolderSeg.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLiSeg.before($newFormLi);

    // add a delete link to the new form
    addSeguimientoFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
}
function addVisitaForm(collectionHolderVis, $newLinkLiVis) {
    // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
    var prototype = collectionHolderVis.data('prototype');

    // get the new index
    var index = collectionHolderVis.data('index');

    // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
    // instead be a number based on how many items we have
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    // increase the index with one for the next item
    collectionHolderVis.data('index', index + 1);

    // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLiVis.before($newFormLi);

    // add a delete link to the new form
    addVisitaFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
}


function addGarantiaFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
    var $removeFormA = $('<br/><a href="#">Borrar</a><hr/>');
    $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

    $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove the li for the tag form
        $tagFormLi.remove();
    });
}
function addSeguimientoFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
    var $removeFormA = $('<br/><a href="#">Borrar</a><hr/>');
    $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

    $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove the li for the tag form
        $tagFormLi.remove();
    });
}
function addVisitaFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
    var $removeFormA = $('<br/><a href="#">Borrar</a><hr/>');
    $tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

    $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // remove the li for the tag form
        $tagFormLi.remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I changed the style of the labels and widgets. But how can i add a div that surrounds every field(label, error and widget) and another div that sourrounds the widget and of course the help text. Current state: [link](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=768218outlet.png)

Comment: The other style that surrounds the code   needs to go   into the javascript code.